# creating a user control with three datasource , displaymember and valuemember

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, datasource

i want to create a custom user control and i need to get three datasource, displaymember and value member in design time.

i can get datasource with below code:

```
private BindingSource dataSource;

[TypeConverter("System.Windows.Forms.Design.DataSourceConverter, System.Design")]
[Category("Data")]
[RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.Repaint)]
[AttributeProvider(typeof(IListSource))]
[DefaultValue(null)]
public BindingSource DataSource
{
    get
    {
        return this.dataSource;
    }
    set
    {
        if (this.dataSource != value)
        {
            this.dataSource = value;
        }
    }
}
```

i don't know how i must get valuemember and displaymember of related datasource

Answer (score 1):

This is a tutorial on how to do what you are asking

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233787.aspx

Comment: i saw it before but is is not useful.

Comment: i reviewed it before while it was not useful for me. please note  it didn't listed datasources and it didn't list displaymember, i should type the displaymemebr and i need to see list of columns of each datasource in related displaymember.

Answer (score 0):

I have a property that supports Lookup Databinding instead custom control, here the code:

```
    private System.Windows.Forms.ListBox dropdownsource = new ListBox();

    [Category("Data")]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [DefaultValue(null)]
    [System.ComponentModel.Bindable(true)]
    [TypeConverter("System.Windows.Forms.Design.DataSourceConverter, System.Design")]
    [Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.DataSourceListEditor, System.Design", typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
    public object DataSource
    {
        get
        {
            return this.dropdownsource.DataSource;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.dropdownsource.DataSource != value)
                this.dropdownsource.DataSource = value;
        }
    }
```

[databinding](/questions/tagged/databinding)[lookup](/questions/tagged/lookup)[bindable](/questions/tagged/bindable)[datasource](/questions/tagged/datasource)